# m is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("test.jpg")

imgfilename = img.filename

imgb,imgg,imgr = cv2.split(img)
count = 0
```

I've been getting the following error when I try to run my code - this is the error I'm getting:

```
 File "WB.py", line 9, in <module>
    imgb,imgg,imgr = cv2.split(img)
TypeError: m is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

Answer (score 0):

You're generally not supposed to use PIL together with numpy, these libraries don't interact a lot.

From numpy (and opencv)'s point of view, images are just 2D or 3D `array`s of any given type (2D for grayscale, 3D for color). Also `cv2` uses BGR by default...

Start with [`cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) instead of `Image.open(path)`.

Comment: I wouldn't say they "You're generally not supposed to use PIL together with numpy" --- PIL just holds images as an object of type `PIL Image` while numpy holds them as an object of type `numpy ndarray`. `np.array(<PIL image>)` perfectly converts the image to an array, and as PIL has support for more image types (e.g. `.gif`) than `OpenCV` and is a quite common library, I've used them in conjunction here and there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the split function available in [PIL](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html) for this purpose.

`Image.split()`

This is because images are interpreted differently in OpenCV and PIL. Hence you cannot you the functions available in these packages interchangeably.

Comment: If you want to stick with the PIL image class, then yes---use the PIL function. However since OP has posted once before about OpenCV, perhaps you could expand this answer with some suggestions on using OpenCV functions, or how to work between the two with numpy arrays.